# Getting specific values

Tags: c#, php, httpwebrequest

I'm creating a program that will talk to my MySQL server through a web page, I currently use the MySQL system, but in this case it makes my script lag majorly and I am looking for alternate solutions so I'm trying out the HttpWebRequest and I know how to send data to the php page, but I'm not able to find any way to retrieve a specific value that would be returned by PHP.

An example of the code would be my version checker.

```
data = "version=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(version) + "&project=gps";
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(checkurl);
WebReq.Proxy = null;
WebReq.Method = "POST";
WebReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
WebReq.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
Stream PostData = WebReq.GetRequestStream();
PostData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
PostData.Close();
```

Now on the PHP end that would then check the current version against the supplied version and create 1 - 2 values depending on the result.

1) Return the current version and 2) if not current return the update link.

Now sorting out the variables will be easy once I know how to retrieve specific information from the PHP page, the two variables 'checkVersion' and 'versionLink' which would be $checkversion and $versionlink.

So far after all my searching all I have found is tutorials on how to send data, and recieve whole pages, not specific values. Is this even possible?

Comment: WUT...Are you trying to program this with PHP or C#?? They are two entire different languages. We need a lot more information here.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding a lot of things here.. PHP is not client side, It's server side, just like c#.

Comment: I'm trying to get the C# code to retrieve specific php values from the page.

Comment: The C# code you posted makes no sense with that comment. The C# code you posted is making a POST request to some url, not getting data from a url.

Comment: Yes it will post that data to the web page, then I need it to retrieve specific PHP values which I will assign to variables in C#.

Comment: So you're saying this needs to work like an API where you post data from C# to a PHP page which does some processing, and then returns values back to C#, gotcha. That is incredibly unclear from your original question.

Comment: You say your application is lagging when executing your script. Can you show us your script?

Comment: This script runs inside GTA IV, the SQL is probably only lagging under those conditions and not due to the code.

Comment: Sorry yes I require the piece of the code that returns the values back to C#. I already can post to the PHP page, I just need to return specific values.